# Inserting multiple rows to a database in a single call

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0, dataset

I want to insert multiple rows to a database, but I don't want to loop through and insert the rows that way.I am using data set.Data set brings a single table,which will contains some of record.I want to add multiple rows into database.I just want to avoid multiple calls in database.I am open for any suggestion or any example.

Please help me to solve the issue.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you use just plain SQL, combine several queries into one string, separating them by `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With more recent versions (2008, 2008R2) of SQL Server you can add multiple rows in an insert statement:

```
insert into mytable (col1, col2)
  values (1, 2),
         (3, 4),
         (5, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

you may insert through select. e.g.

```
insert into mytable1 (id, name, description)
select 
  id,
  name,
  description
from
  mytable2
where
  condition1=value1
```